# low level Hooker

Tags: c++, windows, function, keyboard, hook

I want to make a hook that will act like "event" (and not with agly GetAsyncKeyState) in C# (I want to do it in C++).
so, I've made a dll with this content: http://pastebin.com/yEHJKSS7 .

well, it doesn't call to Handler Function.

by the way, here's how I used the dll:

```
void KeysHandler(int vkKey, int flags)
{
    if(vkKey == VK_ESCAPE)
        exit(0);
    File << vkKey << endl << flags << endl;
}

int main
{
    SetHandler(HandlerFunc);
    //sleep here
}
```

edit: now I saw how I can "debug" in the dll, here are the findings: the SetWindowsHookEx returns 255 - i think it's starnge because it worth to char exactly - I'm going to check in the documentation what does it mean.

edit: 255 is valid return value :O only NULL (0) is error.

I have no idea what's the problem.

edit: well, now my friend brought me a hooker that worked for him. and guess... it didn't work.

I decided it's very strange so I did GetLastError and got 127 - procedure haven't found.
I don't see any reason my procedure won't be found, help please :(

Comment: Patty the low-level daytime hooker?

Comment: +1 for a title which made me read this question :)

Comment: Title intrigued me, actual question disappointed me.

Comment: Amazing, even a suitably worded question on SO can attract kerb crawlers. Er... I'm just passing through, officer.

Comment: @j_random_hacker There is an ongoing attempt to decruft SO (see SO blog for details)  by removing many meta tags - please don't introduce new ones.

Comment: @Neil: at least he didn't use tags as a vector for personal attacks like one I had to roll back yesterday.

Comment: I'm not doing that for hacking purpose. it's an Api that jumps if you press a specific set of keys.
If you know, why won't you show me you're not spammers?

Comment: @Ohad: Nobody called you a hacker.  j_random_hacker is a user on SO who edited your post inappropriately.  Neil was complaining about him, not you.

Comment: Ok, thanks.

Well, now I think it's not the problem - I ran the program and I saw that the lowlevelproc isn't called.

Comment: I edited my question, did anyone ever had anything to do with it?

Comment: The spelling might indeed disturb some people, shouldn't we correct it?

Comment: "I want to make a hooker"
Programming won't bring you forward then, son.

Comment: "Low Level Hooker", one of the funniest question titles so far :)

Comment: @Neil: Fair enough.  But I sorta liked it more when SO had room for some fun, just around the edges :)

Answer (score 1):

Is your main really only calling SetHandler followed by sleep?

You need a MessageLoop in order for any events to be called.

Comment: for now, I try the hooker on console window. in the SetWindowHookEX there should be the "message loop" of the keyboard, and the procedure is in the dll too. @Philipp &(|) Frank: I'm really sorry that my native tongue is'nt english. I do my best.

Comment: OK, I found a direction(I edited ,y question), but I don't know exactly what happen, because my friend told me it works for him.